# recursively mix strings

Tags: python, recursion

I'm trying to link two string together recursively, but not getting the expected results:

For the two strings `"abcd"` and `"xyz"` - expected output should be `"axbyczd"`:

```
def strr(str1, str2):

    def recstr(str1, str2, prn):
        if str1 == '':
            return str2
        if str2 == '':
            return str1
        else:
            return prn + recstr(str1[:len(str1)-len(prn)],str2[:len(str2)-len(prn)],prn)
    return recstr(str1, str2, '')

print strr("abcdef","12345")
```

Comment: A non-recursive `itertools`-based solution would be `"".join(chain.from_iterable(izip_longest(s1, s2, fillvalue="")))`.

Comment: It will recurse indefinitely because the first recursive call is `return '' + recstr(str1[:len(str1)-0]), str2[:len(str2)-0], ''`

Comment: This is the 3rd or 4th variant of this homework question...

Comment: `a[0]+b[0]+strr(a[1:],b[1:]) if a and b else a+b` should do the trick.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you ran out of characters in either string, you returned the other string without concatenating it to a running accumulator. Look at what I do when `s1` or `s2` is empty.

Also, in your recursive case, you have a very complex slicing of `s1` and `s2`. You should really only need to slice `s1[1:]` and `s2[1:]`

This should do it

```
def recstr(s1, s2, answer=''):
    if not s1:
        return answer+s2
    if not s2:
        return answer+s1
    return recstr(s1[1:], s2[1:], answer+s1[0]+s2[0])

In [15]: s1,s2 = 'abcd', 'xyz'

In [16]: print recstr(s1,s2)
axbyczd
```

Of course, a much cleaner way to do this would be to use [`itertools.izip_longest`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) and [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable):

```
In [23]: zips = itertools.izip_longest(s1,s2, fillvalue='')

In [24]: ''.join(itertools.chain.from_iterable(zips))
Out[24]: 'axbyczd'
```

[Thanks @AshwiniChaudhary for pointing out the `fillvalue` param in `izip_longest`]

Hope this helps

Comment: use `izip_longest` with `fillvalue` :`"".join("".join(x) for x in izip_longest(s1,s2,fillvalue=""))`

Comment: Thanks - this works - but I don't understand why- s1[1:] and s2[1:] only returns bcd, and yz respectively - where/what causes it to step through the string?

Comment: If `s1='abcd`, `s1[0]=a` and `s1[1]=b` and `s1[1:]='bcd'`. The number inside the square brackets is an "index" and in python, strings and lists start at index 0

Comment: but s1[1:] remains 'bcd' - regardless - or does the subsequent calls to the same functions keep an "internal" pointer? Sorry - I guess this is why I'm finding recursive functions so hard to understand...

Comment: When you pass `s1[1:]` to the recursive call, in the recursive call, `s1='bcd'`. So when you call `s1[1:]` on that, you get `'cd'`. You should really ask your professor about this - it should be well explained in class